# Find filename from Application Assembly manifest

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I read the manifest for an exe. Something like this:

```
//Load Assembly 
obj_assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(m_strAssembly);
//Return Referenced Assemblies
return obj_assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

and I get an assembly object like "{Tools, Version=5.4.620.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}" for example. How do I know if it is coming from "Tools.dll" or "Tools.exe"? Is there some property in the Assembly object or some trick that tells if it was an EXE or DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, assemblies don't have a fixed filename extension.  Something you can see with Fuslogvw.exe (log all binds).  You'll see it searching for an .exe first, then a .dll.

Some observable side effects: you can add a reference to an EXE without a problem.  Or you can arbitrarily rename a class library assembly from .dll to .exe and it still works.

The sane thing to do is assume that whomever created this assembly didn't pull stunts like this.  You'd expect a reference assembly to be a class library and stored in a file named `tools.dll`.  Which is a good-enough approximation since actually finding that file isn't exactly that easy.  You'd have to reproduce CLR search rules which can get awfully convoluted, you don't know enough about binding overrides and probing paths.

Comment: You are correct. Just realized I saw that in fuslogvw. I guess I will do a simple search like look for an .exe and then .dll. Hoping they won't pull the trick like tools.dll and tools.exe. I guess then I could look for version number to match and publictoken/culture if they exist. Was hoping to avoid doing something like this... Oh well... Thanks!